# Changing Pixel Aspect Ratio has not effect on playback

Tags: video, video-processing, aspect-ratio, mpeg-4, mp4box

I have an mp4 video with resolution 480x540 which I want to display as 16:9 but without re-encoding it. I tried to set the Pixel Aspect Ratio (PAR) using MP4Box as follows, according to [this guide](http://www.komeil.com/blog/change-mp4-aspect-ratio-mp4box):

`http://www.komeil.com/blog/change-mp4-aspect-ratio-mp4box`

However when playing the file using VLC or the Windows Media Player, the file still doesn't play in 16:9 aspect ratio, so it seems setting the PAR value has no effect.

FFprobe output before changing the PAR value:

`Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x540, 286 kb/s, 30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 16k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)`

FFprobe output after chaning the PAR value:

`Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x540, 286 kb/s, SAR 2:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 16k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)`

Is there any other way to "force" the player use the PAR encoded in the container?

Comment: I am guessing the 480x540 is overriding the PAR on playback

Comment: Weirdly that doesn't happen with every video, I tried a couple of other videos that play using the PAR values. The codec is exactly the same